# filtering a table model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I have 2 checkboxes in an application.
The checkboxes are independent of one another ie one can be selected or both can be selected or neither can be selected.

The checkboxes filter a table model, table is refreshed every 10 seconds.

Before each refresh i get the status of each check box as follows:

```
checkM = checkboxM.isSelected();
checkI = checkboxI.isSelected();
```

After the refresh has occurred i then try and set the checkboxes to what they were as follows:

```
checkboxM.setSelected(checkM);
checkboxI.setSelected(checkI);
```

This is then followed by my if statement to find out which boxes are selected and this is where the problem lies as i cant seem to work out how to apply the filters a) that both checkboxes are selected therefore displaying all rows with content "A" and "B" b) one of the checkboxes is selected s0 that only "A" or "B" is shown or no rows are shown

```
if ((checkM = false) || (checkI = false)){
newFilter("",4);   
}

else{
 newFilter("A",4);
newFilter("B",4);


}



//this is my filter

private void newFilter(String x, Integer n) {
sorterDG = new TableRowSorter (modelImbalanceTable);
sorterDG.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(x,n));
tableDG.setRowSorter(sorterDG);
tableDG.tableChanged(new TableModelEvent(tableDG.getModel())) ;
tableDG.repaint();
}
```

Comment: 1) You've described a requirement or specification, but asked no question. What is your question? 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really follow your logic. But if your logic is correct, your problem is just a simply typo. You used `=` where you probably wanted to use `==`. `=` assigns new values to checkM and checkI and at the same time evaluates to the set value. `==` would compare the value. Besides that, comparing a boolean to get a boolean is not really helpful. Just use the boolean as is.

However, this means you currently always execute your `else` path and never your `if` path. And inside your `if` path you have your next problem. You do not accumulate filters, but you first set filter `A`, then `B`. So at runtime you will always end up filtering for `B`, no matter what you have checked.

You probably meant something like

```
if (checkM && checkI) {
    newFilter("A|B", 4);
} else if (checkM) {
    newFilter("A", 4);
} else if (checkI) {
    newFilter("B", 4);
} else {
    newFilter("", 4);
}
```

Comment: @ Björn Kautler. The problem appears to lie with my else statement as i try newFilter("A",4) and then following this i try newFilter("B",4). I want to account if the user ticks checkM or checkI or has both selected or none selected.

Comment: Well and I told you that you don't do it right. You will always enter the else path as I described in my answer. Moreover you will probably always show only "B" values, as you replace your filter with the `newFilter()` call as far as I understand your code.

Comment: Are you able to help?

Comment: I already did help you. I told you where your numerous errors are. Do you expect that I write your code? o_O